# NoReverseMatch error for combined form and model_formset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I have been trying to create a for that combines parent and child models using model_formsets by following use case three in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0).

## Models

```py
class Shoppinglist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) 
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='lists', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    shoppinglist = models.ForeignKey(Shoppinglist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## URLs

```py
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^shoppinglists/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.shoppinglist_list, name='shoppinglist_list'),
   url(r'^shoppinglists/new/$', views.create_shoppinglist_with_items, name='shoppinglist_new'),
]
```

## Forms

```py
class ShoppingListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': 5, 'placeholder': 'Tell us about your list?'}
        ), 
        max_length=4000,
        help_text='The max length of the text is 4000 characters.'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Shoppinglist
        fields = ['name', 'description']

ItemFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Item,
    fields=('name', 'amount'),
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'name': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Enter Item Name here'
            }
        )
    },
    can_delete=True
    
)
```

## View

```py
@login_required
def create_shoppinglist_with_items(request):
    template_name = 'list_with_items.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        listform = ShoppinglistForm(request.GET or None)
        formset = ItemFormset(queryset=Item.objects.none())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        listform = ShoppinglistForm(request.POST)
        formset = ItemFormset(request.POST)
        if listform.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            shoppinglist = listform.save(commit=False)
            shoppinglist.created_by = request.user
            shoppinglist = listform.save()
            for form in formset:               
                item = form.save(commit=False)
                item.shoppinglist = shoppinglist
                item.save()
            return redirect('shoppinglist_list', pk=shoppinglist.pk)
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'listform': listform,
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

## Template

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label>List Name</label>
    {{ listform.name }}
    {% if listform.first_name.errors %}
        {% for error in listform.first_name.errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <label>Description</label>
    {{ listform.description }}
    {% if listform.description.errors %}
        {% for error in listform.description.errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}
        <div class="item-formset">
            {{ form.amount }}
            {% if form.amount.errors %}
                {% for error in form.amount.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ form.name }}
            {% if form.name.errors %}
                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if formset.non_form_errors %}
        {% for error in formset.non_form_errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="row spacer">       
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
<script>
  $('.item-formset').formset({
      addText: 'add item',
      deleteText: 'remove'
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I have modified the code so that the user would be taken to the newly created parent model but instead, when I go to the page I get a NoReverseMatch error.

```
Reverse for 'shoppinglist_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shoppinglists/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: This error doesn't have anything to do with forms or formsets. And it isn't coming from this code. Show the template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have now added the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this ticket there was a typo in the template, which I have corrected, that was causing this issue. So the above code does now work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting model instance.

After you did `shoppinglist = listform.save(commit=False)`, you got the model instance in `shoppinglist` variable.

So you are supposed to do `shoppinglist = shoppinglist.save()` instead of `shoppinglist = listform.save()`

After you save your model instance, you can access the `shoppinglist.pk`.

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't resolved the issue. I think Daniel Roseman is right and it is something to do with the template so I have added it to the original question.